# .click() function not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe which on page load will run .click() function of an anchor link on its parent page. I'm using 
**parent.document.getElementById("abcanchorid").click();**

This works on all browsers except safari. In safari I'm getting,
**TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'parent.document.getElementById("abcanchorid").click()')**

I have tried, **window.location=parent.document.getElementById('abcanchorid').href;**
This is not working since the href of the anchor has reference to other js file variable. Those variables are undefined when called from the iframe.

I tried using jquery and that also did not work,
**$(parent.document.getElementById('abcanchorid')).trigger('click');**
and
**parent.$('#abcanchorid').trigger('click');**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`$("#abcanchorid").click()` should work, especially with jQuery. Why do you need to access the parent node to add the listener?